# Calling p:poll from backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have doubt whether we can call p:poll from backing bean.

I wanted to call p:poll from the backing bean is it possible by using.

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute();`

Thanks,
Brijesh

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? Explain a bit more

Comment: Actually right now i am polling data from backing bean on interval basis so it just sending many request to the server. So i just wanted it to be invoked through backing bean on conditional basis.

Comment: No you can't do that with p:poll. Try Primefaces push for that.

Comment: I am already having prime push but it fails when i am changing data through some webservices/rest call. If we follow normal jsf flow it works fine, but since i am changing data externally. So i used p:poll for pulling data on screen, but it works on interval pattern.

Comment: But what is the problem with using Interval pattern ?

Comment: @Brijesh: try to rephrase your question with your actual needs without mentioning some specific component. Maybe you are trying to "use a screwdriver to tighten a lugnut".

Comment: From your comment "it just sending many requests to the server" - is your server overloaded by poll requests? Is this your problem, server overload?

Comment: @Mindwin : my questions is self explanatory and very straight forward. May be you can ignore it instead of writing it as "use a screwdriver to tighten a lugnut" because it doesn't make me much difference.